# slicing a matrix in python vs matlab

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, slice

After being a MATLAB user for many years, I am now migrating to python.

I try to find a concise manner to simply rewrite the following MATLAB code in python:

```
s = sum(Mtx);
newMtx = Mtx(:, s>0);
```

where Mtx is a 2D sparse matrix

My python solution is:

```
s = Mtx.sum(0)
newMtx = Mtx[:, np.where((s>0).flat)[0]] # taking the columns with nonzero indices
```

where Mtx is a 2D CSC sparse matrix

The python code is not as readable / elegant as in matlab.. any idea how to write it more elegantly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a concise answer, thanks to the lead of rayryeng:

```
s = Mtx.sum(0)
newMtx = Mtx[:,(s.A1 > 0)]
```

another alternative is:

```
s = Mtx.sum(0)
newMtx = Mtx[:,(s.A > 0)[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
s = Mtx.sum(0);
newMtx = Mtx[:,nonzero(s.T > 0)[0]]
```

Source: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-13d7391dd7e2c57d293809cff080260b46d8e664)

It's less obfuscated compared to your version, but according to the guide, this is the best you'll get!

Comment: Too bad there nothing more concise.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, it didn't work for me. The reason was that s is a matrix type and not an array type.

Comment: Didn't tell me what type you were using. I assumed vector / array from your code. Ah well. Glad you found it. FWIW, you could have searched before posting. Save some bandwidth!

Answer (score 0):

Try using find to get the row and col index matching the find criteria

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import scipy.sparse as sp
  
# Creating a 3 * 4 sparse matrix
sparseMatrix = csr_matrix((3, 4), 
                          dtype = np.int8).toarray()

sparseMatrix[0][0] = 1
sparseMatrix[0][1] = 2
sparseMatrix[0][2] = 3
sparseMatrix[0][3] = 4
sparseMatrix[1][0] = 5
sparseMatrix[1][1] = 6
sparseMatrix[1][2] = 7
sparseMatrix[1][3] = 8
sparseMatrix[2][0] = 9
sparseMatrix[2][1] = 10
sparseMatrix[2][2] = 11
sparseMatrix[2][3] = 12

# Print the sparse matrix
print(sparseMatrix)

B = sparseMatrix > 7 #the condition
row, col, data = sp.find(B)
print(row,col)
for a,b in zip(row,col):
    print(sparseMatrix[a][b])
```